# Custom Admin View and User Restriction

Tags: django-admin

I want to create a custom view in django admin that mirrors a change form from another model. I've got as far as creating a custom model admin class, and don't know where to go from here. I cant find any good examples for Django 1.8 on how to create a custom admin view.

> Django Version: 1.8

```
class CustomerProductOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    review_template = 'admin/onlineordering/order_template.html'

    def get_urls(self):

        urls = super(CustomerProductOrderAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = patterns('',
            (r'\d+/customer_template/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.customer_template)),
        )
        return my_urls + urls

    def customer_template(self, request, id):

        product_orders = CustomerProductOrder.objects.get(pk=id)

        return render_to_response(self.review_template, {
            'quantity': 'Quantity: %s' % product_orders.quantity,
        }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I have a customer table that belong to this user table.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, limit_choices_to={'groups__name': "customers"})
```

> /app/model/1      #pk = customer.id

The custom form will have this URL

> /app/customform/

When the logged in user goes to /app/customform, they should not see the change form from /app/model/1. They should not see other users change forms. Also, I would like to limit access to the custom form, to a particular group of users. ie this group cannot see /app/model/ but can see /app/customform.

Answer (score 0):

An example for how to add an independent template to admin page

At the model.py file inside the model class add a function

```
def version_summery(self, ):
    batch_d= {}
    fy = {}

    for br in self.batchresult_set.all():
        batch_d[br.name.strip()] =  br.__dict__

    fy['batch_d'] = batch_d.values()
    x = render_to_string('admin/results/result_build_summary.html', fy)

    return x
```

make sure the urls.py knows how to find the template 'result_build_summary.html'

and in the admin.py

```
readonly_fields = ( 'version_summery',)

fieldsets = (
        ('', {
            'fields': ( 'version_summery', ),
        }),
    )
```